# Windows UWP as Screensaver?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10, uwp, screensaver

On Windows 10, can a UWP be launched as a screensaver? If so, how do you register your app with the OS such that it gets listed in the screensaver dialog?

(Windows 8 store apps cannot be screensavers. I cannot find any information on UWPs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am very sorry to disappoint you, but no, you can not set your UWP app as a screensaver provider.

What you could do instead is offering the user to give your app control of the lock screen or wallpaper image. UWP apps are able to set these images even when running in a background task with the [UserProfilePersonalizationSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.aspx) class:

```
// Lock Screen
await UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync(StorageFile);

// Wallpaper
await UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(StorageFile);
```

Comment: So sad. Screensavers are are a tool for passive consumption (weather, news, photos, clock etc). Not to mention, a potentially easy starter project for someone wanting to learn UWPs.