# How to make screen saver be on top of everything

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, screensaver

I have a single page UWP app which worked with a screensaver until I added a contentdialog control.

If it's open, the contentdialog stays on screen even when the screensaver activates.

Can anyone advise what I should look into to resolve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Is the screensaver a part of your application?

Comment: @Dpt "screensaver", you mean a splash? [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686041/windows-uwp-as-screensaver)